# Alternatives to sed extended regular expressions

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I need to run a regular expression to match part of a string. On OS X I would do:

```
echo "$string" | sed -E 's/blah(.*)blah/\1/g'
```

However, this use of `sed` isn't compatible with other platforms, many of which would invoke the same command using `sed -r`.

So what I'm looking for is either a good way to detect which option to use, or a widely available (and compatible) alternative to `sed` that I can try to do the same thing (retrieve part of a string using a pattern).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are alternatives like awk, perl, tr or even pure bash. It depends upon what you want to do.

However for your case you don't really need special regex flag `-E` of sed. You can do:

```
sed 's/blah\(.*\)blah/\1/g'
```

To make it compatible with sed on other platforms.

Comment: Really? Damn! Looks like I have a lot of other scripts to correct as well then! Although this isn't the most direct response to my question as asked, I think it's the most correct as for some reason I (mistakenly) thought I needed special regex to use sub-patterns, didn't realise you just escaped them! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed incredibly annoying. I do something like:

```
SED_EXTENDED_REGEXP_FLAG=-r
case $(uname)
in
    *BSD) SED_EXTENDED_REGEXP_FLAG=-E ;;
    Darwin) SED_EXTENDED_REGEXP_FLAG=-E ;;
esac

echo "$string" | sed $SED_EXTENDED_REGEXP_FLAG 's/blah(.*)blah/\1/g'
```

That's off the top of my head, so apologies if the shell script syntax is a bit off.

This assumes that any platform which is not a BSD or OS X has GNU sed (or another sed where `-r` is the flag for extended regular expressions, if there is such a thing).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In some respects this is the most direct answer to my question as asked, and well worth knowing regardless, but I think @anubhava's answer is what I should actually be using in my case so I've marked that as the answer. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

By far the best solution using `sed` is to use the portable (POSIX) basic regular expression equivalent, which will work on all platforms:

```
echo "$string" | sed -e 's/blah\(.*\)blah/\1/g'
```

This `-e` indicates the `sed`-script follows; it could be omitted.

Failing that, Perl was in part a `sed` substitute (there's still a program `s2p` that converts `sed` scripts into Perl scripts).

```
perl -e 'foreach (@ARGV) { s/blah(.*)blah/$1/; print "$_\n"; }' "$string"
```